# Adding similar variable names to array

Tags: c++, initialization, openfoam

I wrote a c++ programm in openFOAM which works fine. The user can give diameters d_p as an input. This number of diameters can vary so e.g. in one case it could be `d_p1`, `d_p2` and `d_p3` ... in another case it could be only `d_p1` and `d_p2`. What I would like to do is checking first, which diameters are set in an dictionary and add them to an array I can loop over. This would help me to solve my equations for the array with indexing diameter instead of copy paste code for every single varibale.

Does anybody know if/how this is possible? I have read some posts to this in internet but could not find a solution to this :/

EDIT:

Some more details:

I have a dictionary called someProperties which looks like this:

```
d_p1     d_p1     [0 1 0 0 0 0 0]      0.1E-06;
d_p2     d_p2     [0 1 0 0 0 0 0]      100.0E-06;
```

The number of d_p is, like I said, variable. I can read that diameters with another header file called createFields.H with following possible code:

```
IOdictionary someProperties
(
    IOobject
    (
        "someProperties",
        runTime.constant(),
        mesh,
        IOobject::MUST_READ_IF_MODIFIED,
        IOobject::NO_WRITE
    )
);

dimensionedScalar d_p1
(
    CDRProperties.lookup("d_p1")
);

dimensionedScalar d_p2
(
    CDRProperties.lookup("d_p2")
);
```

Later on I would like to use this diameters in my normal code. To loop over the diameters (so I dont need to copy paste my code for all diameters) I need some kind of structure like array or list of scalars with dimensions (this is some kind of openFOAM coding).

Thanks in advance

Pyrokrates

Comment: Are the diameters just a named instance of a Diameter type?

Comment: Why would you need a *dictionary/hashmap* for this? Can't you just store them in a [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) which scales dynamically? Then you can just iterate through it as you would normally do with an array.

Comment: The dictionary in openFOAM is for initialization of the user... meaning if the user want to run the program, he can define parameters inside this dictionary and later on the program read the variables out of this...

Answer (score 0):

Just use `std::vector`. It is basically a dynamic array that grows on demand:

```cpp
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<double> d_p;
  d_p.push_back(1);
  d_p.push_back(2);
  d_p.push_back(3);

  // later on use [] to acces
  d_p[0] = 42; // ...

  // Or iterate
  for (int i = 0; i != d_p.size(); ++i)
    d_p[i] = i * 3.14; // ...
}
```

Comment: That´s what I would like to do but I don´t know the number of d_p entries. How can I realize this?
For example if I have
`d_p1 = 10;`
`dp_2 = 15;`
`dp_3 = 18;`

Comment: @Pyro you can do `d_p.push_back(10); d_p.push_back(15); d_p.push_back(18);`

Comment: That would be the easy way, yes... But I need to define the variables inside a dictionary which is read by the programm while running... If I do it with push_back like this, I need to change the scource code all the time and compile again ... This is not how the tool should work later on.

Comment: @Pyro What do you mean? Could you show a [mre] where I can see how you are planning to use it?

Comment: Hi, I have added some more informtion to the main question on top. Thanks in advance for your help.